# How to forcibly update a file if left unchanged after 55 minutes?

Tags: linux, bash, solaris

I need a log file to be updated if it has been left unchanged during 55 minutes. For example, say it is now 19:00 and `IOstatDisk2.log` hasn't changed since 18:00:

```
 solaris1a:/var/tmp ROOT # ls -ltr IOstatDisk2.log
 -rw-r--r--   1 root    other       6 Aug  2 18:00 IOstatDisk2.log
```

So in this case I will append the line

```
echo “new cycle - forced update after 55 min.” >> IOstatDisk2.log
```

But if the last time stamp was less than 55 minutes ago then I will not append the line.

Comment: Your question is not clear: do you want not less than 55 minutes between updates? Or do you want file updates to stop after 55 minutes? Or do you want to log a warning if the file has been left unchanged after 55 minutes?

Comment: what I want is to write to file only after 55 min that file was not update

Comment: Okay, so you want to forcibly update the log file if it was left unchanged during 55 minutes, right?

Comment: yes right -:) , ......

Comment: please do not cross post : http://superuser.com/questions/949546/solaris-how-to-verify-if-file-isn-t-update-more-than-xx-min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it (and operate on the file if test holds true) in this way:

```
if [ $(((`date +%s` - `stat -c %Y IOstatDisk2.log`) / 60)) -ge 55 ]
then 
   echo "File was modified more than 55 minutes ago"
   # do something with the file...
fi
```

Comment: because I need to run this on both OS ( linux & solaris ) , stat not valid command in solaris

Comment: Check this answer on how to `stat` a file in Solaris: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242473/stat-command-to-capture-last-modified-date-of-file-in-solaris

Comment: date +%s is ok on Linux but on solaris is diff ,

Comment: @maihabunash have you *-r(--reference)* option in `date` command?

Comment: hi - see the solution --> http://serverfault.com/questions/710435/solaris-date-what-is-the-same-equivalent-for-solaris

Answer (score 1):

GNU `find` or BSD `find` will do the trick for you:

```
find <DIRECTORY> -type f -amin +55 -name \*<PATTERN>\* -print
```

this will print all files with name PATTERN in DIRECTORY which where accessed *greater than* 55 mins ago.

Comment: do you know what is the syntax for solaria? ( for linux its OK , But I need to run this command also on solaria )

Comment: @maihabunash Type `find --help` on Solaris to get the answer.

Comment: Find with xargs or a while loop will do it.